# How to find the maximum number that cannot be derived by the addition of 3 numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, multilinear-algebra

I am working on a project where I am trying to achieve a secure way to transmit data as numbers. **It aims to find the maximum number that could not be derived from addition of given three or more numbers.**

For example;
$A = \{3,7,9\}$

This problem can be formulated as:

$3a+7b+9c\ne x$ where $a,b,c\ge0$

and then finding the maximum by hand.

$x$ can be equal to $3,6,7,9,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,...$

Therefore, for $A$ the answer is 11 as all the positive real numbers bigger than 11 can be written as a summation of 3, 7 and 9.

**Is there anyway I could find the numbers that apply to the rule for a given set without calculating it manually?**

I found a code to [Find the smallest positive integer value that cannot be represented as sum of any subset of a given array](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-smallest-value-represented-sum-subset-given-array/) but nothing about biggest positive integer.

Comment: See here: https://people.math.ethz.ch/~blatter/geomfrob.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is equivalent to finding the frobenius number of a numerical semigroup with generators $\{3,7,9\}$ which is equivalent to the semigroup generated by $\{3,7\}$ since $9$ can generated by $3\cdot 3$.

Usually, finding the frobenius number is non-trivial, but there is an explicit formula if the semigroup is generated by just two generators $x$ and $y$: $xy-x-y$. In the case of $x=3$ and $y=7$, we have $xy-x-y = 3(7)-3-7 =11$ which is consistent with your result.

Resources: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_semigroup

Edit: if you'd like to leave the problem for a CAS to solve, then I know GAP has some methods for calculating things involving numerical semigroups, possibly including the frobenius number. There is also a Sage Numerical Semigroups wrapper out there if you'd prefer to call those GAP functions from within Sage.

Comment: For GAP, see its NumericalSgps package by Manuel Delgado,
Pedro A. Garcia-Sanchez and Jose Morais: htttp://cmup.fc.up.pt/cmup/mdelgado/numericalsgps/. It is included in the GAP distribution (https://www.gap-system.org/Releases/).

Comment: In particular, it calculates the Frobenius number. For example, `FrobeniusNumberOfNumericalSemigroup(NumericalSemigroup(3,5,7))` returns 4. See http://cmup.fc.up.pt/cmup/mdelgado/numericalsgps/doc/chap3.html#X7B7DFAB2834B2B36

Comment: @AlexanderKonolov I just learned about GAP and I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am getting error, variable not defined. Can you help me through it?

Comment: I assume you mean the command from my comment - it's in a package that is not loaded by default. To get it, first call `LoadPackage("NumericalSgps");`. Also, remember that GAP is case-sensitive.

Comment: @KeithN by the way, I discovered your comment about undefined variable just accidentally - you made a typo in my username so the ping did not work ;-)